# Embedded neo4j with tinkerpop - Same Instance,Multiple access

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop

I see that 'blueprints-neo4j-graph-2.5.0' is the latest released version to use tinkerpop blueprints api with neo4j graph which is version 1.9.6.

A few questions on this:

1. I understand that this neo4j instance will be an embedded database with community version. Is that right? If so, how do I switch to enterprise version?

   I tried including this as gradle dependency:    compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-enterprise', version:'2.0.1'

   But, I think 'blueprints-neo4j-graph-2.5.0' will get its own version(neo4j 1.9.6) as a dependency.
2. Is it possible to use neo4j webadmin console with the embedded version?

   I tried changing the database location in neo4j.server.properties to the same location as given in the configuration for embedded instance, but I am not able to access them simultaneously.

I made this change in my build.gradle.

compile group: 'com.tinkerpop.blueprints', name: 'blueprints-neo4j2-graph', version:'2.5.0'

This picks up neo4j 2.0.1.

Also, I changed the tinkerpopConfig ( I am using GraphFactory to open and close the graph) as mentioned in tinkerpop sample to be:

```
"blueprints.neo4jha.directory" : "C:/data/my-test-model-graph",
"blueprints.graph" : "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2HaGraph",
"blueprints.neo4jha.conf.server_id" : "1",
"blueprints.neo4jha.conf.server" : "localhost:6364",
"blueprints.neo4jha.conf.cluster_server" : "localhost:5002",
"blueprints.neo4jha.conf.initial_hosts" : "localhost:5001,localhost:5002"
```

Now when I try to deploy, I get a null graph.

When you said, HA implementation requires Enterprise edition:

I also tried doing it this way,

```
compile(group: 'com.tinkerpop.blueprints', name: 'blueprints-neo4j2-graph', version:'2.5.0'){
exclude(module: 'neo4j')
exclude(module: 'neo4j-ha')
exclude(module: 'neo4j-management')
    }
compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-enterprise', version:'2.0.1'
```

which will get neo4j-enterprise-2.0.1.

But this also doesn't seem to work and is not able to open a graph instance.

Do you see anything odd here?

`java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2HaGraph].
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:50) ~[blueprints-core-2.5.0.jar:na]
at com.repo.GraphManager.getGraphDatabase(GraphManager.java:314) [com.repo~repo_module~1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/:na]
at com.repo.GraphManager.start(GraphManager.java:164) [com.repo~repo_module~1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/:na]
at org.vertx.java.platform.Verticle.start(Verticle.java:82) [vertx-platform-2.1M1.jar:na]
at com.englishtown.vertx.hk2.HK2VerticleLoader.start(HK2VerticleLoader.java:77) [com.englishtown~vertx-mod-hk2~1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/:na]
at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$19.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1551) [vertx-platform-2.1M1.jar:na]
at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:176) [vertx-core-2.1M1.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:43) ~[blueprints-core-2.5.0.jar:na]
... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1124) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1162) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.applyChanges(Config.java:122) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.<init>(Config.java:88) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.<init>(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:278) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:136) ~[neo4j-ha-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.java:47) ~[neo4j-ha-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2HaGraph.<init>(Neo4j2HaGraph.java:23) ~[blueprints-neo4j2-graph-2.5.0.jar:na]
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2HaGraph.<init>(Neo4j2HaGraph.java:31) ~[blueprints-neo4j2-graph-2.5.0.jar:na]
... 14 common frames omitted`

Answer (score 0):

If you want Neo4j 2.x then you need to use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
  <artifactId>blueprints-neo4j2-graph</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As this version runs in embedded mode only one JVM process at a time can access the database, so you can't access a database via TinkerPop and have Neo4j Server running at the same time to get the Neo4j WebAdmin Console.  If you want to run in that mode then you should use `Neo4jHaGraph`:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Neo4jHa-Implementation

which requires Enterprise Edition:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html

`Neo4jHaGraph` should also exist in the `blueprints-neo4j2-graph` packaging.

Comment: How are you managing dependencies?  using Maven? my initial guess is that there are some Neo4j 1.x dependencies in the mix, but that's just a guess given the stack trace you posted.

Comment: I am using gradle for dependencies. In lib directory, I don't see any jars from 1.x.

Comment: Updated the question post now.

Comment: After cleaning the local gradle cache, it works now with neo4j 2.1.2. The other issue I see now is:

I have two VMs with their own database instances and are deployed in HA mode. I see following messages in messages.log:
http://pastie.org/9577035

I believe it should say something like:
Attempting to join cluster of [first host:port, second host:port], instead I see it only has the host:port of it's own.

If I deploy them directly with neo4j core java apis, they get clustered and have expected behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if you posted this issue in GitHub or not: https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/issues/507 Anyway, we'll look to get to resolution there.